# awaitを使った処理でWebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null)が待機されない原因が知りたい。

Tags: c#

#### コードについて

提示コードはWebView2を使ってhtmlを描画するクラスとその初期化処理です。

#### 知りたい事

`webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);`の処理が`///`コメント部内部の`Form1()`で実行されない原因が知りたい。

#### 試したこと

`webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);`を`form()`関数で`InitializeAsync();`の中で実行されないので`Init()`関数を作ってその中で実行しましたが実行されていませんでした。

`view.Render()`関数内の描画処理に混ぜて行うと実行されるためawaitが原因と考えられるのですがなぜでしょうか? `しっかりawaitで待機しています。`

参考サイトBを参考に関数を作成して試しましたが実行されていません。

##### 参考サイト

参考サイトA： https://zenn.dev/vatscy/articles/ba2263bdfadfeb805379
参考サイトB： https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66550671/ensurecorewebview2async-not-ready-even-after-corewebview2initializationcompleted

##### Form1.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public record Sample
    (
        string userName,
        string test,
        bool IsDelete
    );


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private HtmlView view;
        /// string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"debug.js");
        
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private async void Init()
        {
            await view.webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
        }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            
            view = new HtmlView(new Size(Size.Width, Size.Height),this);
            //view.InitializeAsync();

            Init();

            view.Render("asset/index.html");
            view.Show();

        }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
}
```

##### HtmlView

```cs
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public class HtmlView
    {
        public WebView2 webView;

        public HtmlView(Size size,Form form) 
        {

            webView = new WebView2();
            webView.Size = size;
            webView.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
            webView.BringToFront();

            form.Controls.Add(webView);

            //InitializeAsync();

        }

        public async void InitializeAsync()
        {
            await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
        }


        public void Show()
        {
            webView.Show();
        }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public async void Render(string path)
        {
            
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("asset/index.html",Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
            string str = sr.ReadToEnd();

            await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);

            webView.NavigateToString(str);                    
        }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public async void setJS(string path)
        {
            StreamReader srr = new StreamReader("asset/script/Main.js", Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
            string ss = srr.ReadToEnd();
            await webView.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync(ss);

        }


        public void JsonStringData(string jsonPath)
        {
            StreamReader str = new StreamReader("asset/test.json", Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
            string json = str.ReadToEnd();
            webView.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsJson(json);


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async void Init()` とありますが、radianさんから [Xabe.FFmpegで動画ファイルがエンコードされない原因が知りたいの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/92059/4236)で

> イベントハンドラ以外のasync voidはやめましょう

とアドバイスを受けたのは覚えていますか？ また私からは[同回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/92068/4236)で

> `Form1_Load`メソッドが無難です。

とも提案したはずです。これらには意味があってのことです。というのも

> ```
> public Form1()
> {
>     InitializeComponent();
>
>     view = new HtmlView(new Size(Size.Width, Size.Height),this);
>     //view.InitializeAsync();
>
>     Init();
>
>     view.Render("asset/index.html");
>     view.Show();
> }
> ```

と`Form1`コンストラクタに処理を書かれていますが、コンストラクタ実行中はまだフォームを表示していません。そのことは、呼び出し元の`Program.cs`を読むとわかります。

```
static void Main() {
    ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

となっていて、`Form1`コンストラクタが完了してから`Application.Run()`が実行されます。UI処理（メッセージループ）はこの中で動きます。

---

> 質問ですがform_load関数にて以下のような関数の中にawaitがあるにもかかわらず関数の外ににもawaitを書かなないといけない理由がはなんでしょうか?

その理由もradianさんの回答にある[非同期プログラミングのベスト プラクティス](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)で説明されています。とりあえず`async`メソッドを呼び出す際は**常に**`await`を付けてください。（そして呼び出し元が`await`できるようにするためにはメソッド定義として`async void`を避ける必要があります。）

---

[WinForms アプリでの WebView2 の使用を開始する / 手順 10 - ホストと Web コンテンツ間の通信](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms#step-10---communication-between-host-and-web-content)に

> ```
> public Form1()
> {
>    InitializeComponent();
>    this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Form_Resize);
>    webView.NavigationStarting += EnsureHttps;
>    InitializeAsync();
> }
>
> async void InitializeAsync()
> {
>    await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
> }
> ```

このようなコードが載っていて、これを参考にされていたんですね。残念ながら、このサンプルコードは非同期プログラミングのベスト プラクティスにも準じておらず正しくないコードです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問ですがform_load関数にて以下のような関数の中にawaitがあるにもかかわらず関数の外ににもawaitを書かなないといけない理由がはなんでしょうか? `await view.InitializeAsync();`